# suffixIcon blocks TextFormField's input

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TextFormField and I wish to display a button at the end of the input field. I was advised to use suffixIcon to do so, yet when I do, the input field itself doesn't let me type anything. I'm guessing the button somehow blocks the input field, and I'm not sure how to work around this.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

```
  Widget get inputField {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
// validateButton would basically be a countdown button. 
          suffixIcon: _validateButton,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get _validateButton {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: countButton(
        duration: 30,
        text: "Confirm",
        onPressed: () => sent()
      ),
    );
  }
```

PS:
If I take alignment out of the _validateButton widget, I get something that works (I get the button inside the input field and I can still use the input field to type) but it doesn't look quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code hope its help to you,

I have used below code `suffixIcon as IconButton`

```
    TextFormField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: _validateButton(),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                ),
              ),
            ),

 _validateButton() {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
           // Call your onPressed function here like(sent())
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.check),
    );
  }
```

I have used below code `suffixIcon as TextButton`

```
  TextFormField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: _validateButton(),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                ),
              ),
            ),



_validateButton() {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
           // Call your onPressed function here like(sent())
       },
      child: Text('Confirm'),
    );
  }
```

Your Output Screen Using **IconButton** -> [image]

Your Output Screen Using **TextButton** -> [image]

Comment: I still need to use my validateButton though

Comment: @someJoe121 I have update the answer